# Scala Futures on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to get Scala (Play) Iteratees working on Google App Engine.  My goal is to use Iteratees with the App Engine Channel Api.

So far I extracted `play.api.libs.iteratee` from Play2.1.5, and created an `ExecutionContext` that uses appengines `ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory`.

The Scala 2.10 Future implementation uses classes that aren't on AppEngines whitelist like `Unsafe.java`.

Is there something shortcut for getting Iteratees working on AppEngine, or does it depend on having a Future implementation that works on GAE?